# whats the exact return of value in " " in c? is it a pointer?

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers

I know that "Ali" is char array with 4 character: 'A' 'l' 'i' NULL

What i wanna know is the return value of it.

for example strcpy needs two pointer as input. why is the code below working:

```
    char mstr[10]={};
    strcpy(mstr,"Working...");
```

but this is not :

```
    char *names[5]={"Ali","Reza","Hassan","Ahmad","Mohammad"};
```

"Ali" is a pointer to 'A' character or not?!

---

problem fixed!!! (i cant understand why?! i just add something to print them!) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char mstr[10]={};
    strcpy(mstr,"Working...");
    char *names[5]={"Ali","Reza","Hassan","Ahmad","Mohammad"};
    int i;
    //print :
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        puts(names[i]);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

---

I think i find out what happened here. my second code is completely correct in C. I was compiling it as a c++ file (it was a cpp file)

By the way error was :  [Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

C++ has different rules and by default it defined 5 const char arrays not char arrays.

I think it was the answer.

Comment: What do you by "not working"?  That should compile fine.

Comment: no its not working at all ... [Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: It's compiling fine here: http://ideone.com/5mGMLH.  Please post a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: fpermissive is for C++ code, not C code. Why are you using that flag?

Comment: i cant understand in dev its not working ...

Comment: @Mike there is no difference its not working in a c file too...

Comment: Again, please post the exact code that you're using.  Also, please post details about your compiler version, and how you're invoking it.

Comment: there is no more code... why its not working ... im using devc++ 5.5.3 its a c file and windows will stop compiling it...

Comment: I don't believe that *that* error message could arise from *that* line of code, whether you're compiling C or C++.  For a start, you don't have anything here of type `char`.

Comment: Regarding your query about `"Ali"` being a pointer to `'A'` - it depends on the context. By itself `"Ali"` is a literal declaration of an array of characters large enough to hold four elements, with the first three initialized to `'A', 'l', 'i'` and the last character set to NUL (note: NUL, not NULL). If this literal is used in a function call where a `char *` is expected (e.g. `strcpy(name, "Ali");`) the compiler follows the rule that a literal array declaration used where a pointer is expected results in a pointer to the first element of the array being passed to the function.

Comment: i meant first it was a cpp file but i changed it to a c file. compiling error in dev fixed but windows still cant compile the file

Comment: :O !!!!! Problem fixed! i just add an array to print the names strings and its working now!!

Comment: i think i found out the answer myself: it was still compiling the cpp file (im so sorry about my mistake) but im still confused ... why its wrong in c++ ?!

Comment: `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant. The null *character* is `'\0'`.

Comment: When I compile your code *as C++* using g++, I get "warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]". If you want to ask about C++, please change the tag on your question and update it to make it clear what you're asking. Include the exact error message in the body of your question, not buried in a comment.

Comment: @KeithThompson ty. there is no need. it was a c question not c++ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, this declaration:

```
char *names[5]={"Ali","Reza","Hassan","Ahmad","Mohammad"};
```

is perfectly legal, but potentially dangerous. It defines `names` as an array of 5 `char*` pointers, each of which points to the first character of a string literal. The problem is that attempting to modify a string literal has undefined behavior (string literals aren't `const` for historical reasons). So this declaration allows you to do something like:

```
names[0][0] = 'E'; /* rename Ali to Eli? */
```

with no complaint from the compiler; it's likely to crash during execution. (A compiler is permitted, but not required, to warn about this.)

The above *should* be written as:

```
const char *names[5]={"Ali","Reza","Hassan","Ahmad","Mohammad"};
```

which makes `names` an array of 5 pointers to `const` (read-only) `char`.

As for why the code is not working for you, it's because you attempted to compile it as C++ (which you mentioned only in a commment). C++ is a different language than C, and has different rules. (In C++ the conversion is permitted but deprecated.) If you want to ask about C++, please post a new question with the C++ tag -- and be sure to clearly show the exact error message in the body of the question, not buried in a comment.

Comment: I got all the answers i wanted. ty all :) and sorry for burring it in a comment .

Comment: But it's still not clear what you were asking. I'd still ask you to update your question to make it clear just what you were asking, so the question and answers together might be more useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Study the following - perhaps it will help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
  char mstr[11];  /* must be **11** elements in size to hold "Working..." */
  char *names[5]={"Ali","Reza","Hassan","Ahmad","Mohammad"};
  int i;

  strcpy(mstr, "Working...");
  printf("Print #1 - mstr='%s'\n", mstr);

  for(i = 0 ; i < sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0]) ; ++i)
     printf("Print #2 - names[%d] = '%s'\n", i, names[i]);
  }
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score -2):

Strings in C are pointers to `char` (= `char *`). The value of `"foo"` is, as you said, a pointer. The reason your second example doesn't work is that `char *names[5]` is a pointer to `char *` (= `char **`). It's not a string, it's an array of strings, and since arrays are pointers, it's a pointer to a string. Since strings are arrays (= pointers) of characters, it's a pointer-to-a-pointer-to-char.

Comment: The type of `"foo"` is actually `char [4]`...

Comment: it must be a pointer to pointer to pointer! its an array of strings.

Comment: @user2933210 Yes, and `printf()` and friends don't want pointers-to-pointers, they want pointers-to-characters.

Comment: char * names is an array of pointers which each one must be a start of a string. if "foo" is a pointer to 'f' so it must work!

Comment: `char *names[5]` is a declaration of an array of 5 pointers-to-character. If/when `names` is used by itself, however, the C rule that the name of an array, by itself, generates a pointer to the first element of the array, and thus `names` by itself is equivalent to a `char **`. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @user2933210 How about you post the rest of the code (the part where you're trying to use `names`) so we can take a look? `names` is NOT a pointer to a character. It's a pointer to an ARRAY of strings (an array of pointers to arrays). Which is a "double pointer." Big difference.

Comment: @DavidNorris - `names` is not a pointer to an array of characters, it's a pointer to an array of character pointers. A pointer to an array of characters would be `char *`.

Comment: @BobJarvis: Technically it would be `char (*)[N]` (for some constant `N`).

Comment: @BobJarvis Yes, I misspoke, sorry. It's a pointer to an array of elements; those elements are pointers to arrays of characters. What `printf()` wants is a pointer to an array of characters.

Comment: @BobJarvis thank you ... but its not explain the error...

Comment: @user2933210 I think it's been explained very well, you're just not listening. You haven't posted enough code for anyone to be able to help you more than the explanations already given (which I think you will understand if you give it a try instead of insisting that your code "should" work).

Comment: ty all. i was listening, but your explanation just confirmed my code not tell the cause of error...

Comment: @DavidNorris: No, what `printf` wants is a pointer to `char` (`char*`), *not* a pointer to an array of characters (`char (*)[N]`).

Comment: A "string" is by definition "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character". It is *not* a pointer of any kind. "*and since arrays are pointers*" -- no, they absolutely are not. Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/), and please either fix this answer or delete it.

Comment: @KeithThompson Pointers are integral to use of strings in C, and the OP is having trouble with that concept. The FAQ is a good link and good read which would probably be helpful to the OP. Nitpicking on technical definitions and specifications is probably less useful IMHO.

Comment: @DavidNorris: Claiming that "arrays are pointers" helps to spread one of the worst and most common misconceptions about C. Arrays are not pointers. This is not "nitpicking on technical definitions"; this is being clear about fundamental concepts of the language.